# Loop sobre un excel y un power point

Tags: excel, vba, bucles

Poniendo que tengo un excel con varias graficas, una en cada hoja, y un power point ya creado y de ruta conocida donde quiero pegar esas graficas como imagen, una por diapositiva. ¿Como podria hacerlo?

Muchas gracias por adelantado

Answer (score 0):

Aquí tienes las respuesta. Sacada de otro hilo en inglés: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7492519/paste-excel-chart-into-powerpoint-using-vba

```
Const ppLayoutBlank = 2
Const ppViewSlide = 1

Sub ExportChartstoPowerPoint()
    Dim PPApp As Object
    Dim chr
    Set PPApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
    PPApp.Presentations.Add
    PPApp.ActiveWindow.ViewType = ppViewSlide
    For Each chr In Sheets("Chart1").ChartObjects
        PPApp.ActivePresentation.Slides.Add PPApp.ActivePresentation.Slides.Count + 1, ppLayoutBlank
        PPApp.ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide PPApp.ActivePresentation.Slides.Count
        chr.Select
        ActiveChart.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Size:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
        PPApp.ActiveWindow.View.Paste
        PPApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Align msoAlignCenters, True
        PPApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Align msoAlignMiddles, True
    Next chr
    PPApp.Visible = True
End Sub
```

La idea es recorrer toda la coleccion de gráficos y por cada gráfico encontrado decirle que lo añada a un slide (diapositiva) diferente.